# What is Inverse Fourier Transform of $2^2/(^2−^2)$?

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

What is the inverse Fourier transform of  $F(w) = \frac{4}{4+(j2\pi f)^2} $?
 I have two suggested solutions:

1. Assume $j2\pi f = \omega$ and use the standard transform
   $e^{-\alpha |\tau |} = \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha ^2 + \omega ^2}$ to obtain $\frac{1}{4}e^{-2|\tau|}$
2. Calculate $f(\tau) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}e^{i\omega\tau}d\omega$

For (2), how can I solve the integral in order to get the inverse Fourier transform $f(\tau)$?

Answer (score 0):

In general Fourier transform (or inverse) take products into convolutions.  Let $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ have transforms $f(t)$ and $g(t)$.  Then the transform of $F(x)G(x)$ is $h(t)=\int f(s)g(t-s)ds$.

For your problem  $f(t)=\frac{1}{16}\int e^{-a|s|-b|t-s|}ds$ where $a=2$ and $b=8$.

(Note:  I may have constant wrong, but you see the point.)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\eqa}{\approx}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\brlr}[1]{\left.#1\right|}$
$\newcommand{\deriv} [2]   {{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2} }}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\intcc} [2]  {{\left[#1:#2\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\intoo} [2]  {{\left(#1:#2\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\intoc} [2]  {{\left(#1:#2\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\intco} [2]  {{\left[#1:#2\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\ff}{\mathrm{f}}$
$\newcommand{\fF}{\mathrm{F}}$
$\newcommand{\fG}{\mathrm{G}}$
$\newcommand{\fg}{\mathrm{g}}$
$\newcommand{\fphi}{\mathrm{\phi}}$
$\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{dx}}$
$\newcommand{\dtau}{\mathrm{d\tau}}$
$\newcommand{\du}{\mathrm{du}}$
$\newcommand{\dv}{\mathrm{dv}}$

It looks like there *is* some problem with the answer in "1."
First note that it is indeed true that the Fourier Transform $\fG(\omega)$ of
the function $\fg(\tau)\eqd e^{-\alpha\abs{\tau}}$ is
$\fG(\omega)\eqd\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}$.
Assuming the definition of the Fourier Transform used is
$\fG(\omega)\eqd \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\fg(\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}\dtau$,
we can check the relation as follows:
\begin{align}
  \fG(\omega)
    &\eqd \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\fg(\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}\dtau
    && \text{by definition Fourier Transform}
  \\&\eqd \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha\abs{\tau}} e^{-j\omega\tau}\dtau
    && \text{by definition of $\fg(\tau)$}
  \\&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-\alpha(-\tau)} e^{-j\omega\tau}\dtau
     + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha(\tau)} e^{-j\omega\tau}\dtau
  \\&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{\tau(\alpha-j\omega)}\dtau
     + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\tau(-\alpha-j\omega)}\dtau
  \\&= \brlr{\frac{e^{\tau(\alpha-j\omega)}}{\alpha-j\omega}}_{-\infty}^{0} 
     + \brlr{\frac{e^{\tau(-\alpha-j\omega)}}{-\alpha-j\omega}}_{0}^{\infty} 
    && \text{by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus}
  \\&= \brs{\frac{1}{\alpha-j\omega} - 0}
     + \brs{0- \frac{1}{-\alpha-j\omega}}
  \\&= \brs{\frac{1}{\alpha-j\omega}}\brs{\frac{\alpha+j\omega}{\alpha+j\omega}}
     + \brs{\frac{1}{\alpha+j\omega}}\brs{\frac{\alpha-j\omega}{\alpha-j\omega}}
    && \text{(to rationalize the denominator)}
  \\&= \frac{\alpha+j\omega}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}
     + \frac{\alpha-j\omega}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}
  \\&= \boxed{\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}}
\end{align}

And so the Inverse Fourier Transform (IFT) of $\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}$
is $e^{-\alpha\abs{\tau}}$.

However, your question does not ask for the IFT of
$\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}=\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+(2\pi f)^2}$,
but rather for the IFT of
$$
  \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+(j2\pi f)^2}
    = \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+(j\omega)^2}
    =\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}
$$

Comment: can you show me the steps to get the IFT?

Comment: I have tried to find the IFT but so far haven't been successful. I will work more on it though. Maybe someone else already knows the answer and could post it here?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%224%2F%284-w%5E2%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22) has something interesting to say. In essence ...
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{4}{4-\omega^2}e^{i\tau\omega}d\omega 
= -\frac{i}{2}e^{-2i\tau}(-1+e^{4i\tau})sgn(\tau)
$$

Comment: \begin{align}
  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{4}{4-\omega^2}e^{i\tau\omega}d\omega 
    &= -\frac{i}{2}e^{-2i\tau}(-1+e^{4i\tau})sgn(\tau)
  \\&= -\frac{i}{2}(-e^{-2i\tau}+e^{2i\tau})sgn(\tau)
  \\&= -\frac{i}{2}[2i\sin(2\tau)]sgn(\tau)
    && \text{by Euler's Identity}
  \\&= \sin(2\tau)sgn(\tau)
\end{align}

Comment: _Conjecture_: IFT of $\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}$ is $\sin(\alpha\tau)\mathrm{sgn}(\tau)$
$\ldots$ but I'm not sure at this point $\ldots$

Comment: Doesn't seem to work out... $$\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\omega^2} -2 \lim_{t\to\infty}( \frac{\cos[t(\alpha-\omega)]}{\alpha-\omega} + \frac{\cos[t(\alpha+\omega)]}{\alpha+\omega})$$

Comment: thanks. Does this mean that this function does not have an inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: Absence of proof is not proof of absence. It just means that we haven't found the IFT yet. Did you try taking the FT of $\sin(\alpha\tau)\mathrm{sgn}(\tau)$? Any ideas you might have? It's an interesting problem—I'll keep looking for the IFT. Let me know if you find something.

Comment: My lecturer told me to use $j2\pi f$ as $\omega$. then apply the inverse Fourier transform I used in 1 ( in the question).

Comment: What would you think about posting the question separately? Maybe someone who is more familiar with this would see it and answer? That is, maybe you could post:
What is the Inverse Fourier Transform of $$G(\omega)=\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}$$? That is, what is $g(\tau)$ where
$$g(\tau) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}e^{i\omega\tau}d\omega$$
? Maybe use a title something like: What is Inverse Fourier Transform of $2\alpha^2/(\alpha^2-\omega^2)$?

Comment: ok. I could still modify this question

Comment: Maybe consider putting \$ signs around 2^2/(^2−^2) in title so that instead of rendering as "2^2/(^2−^2)", it would render as "$2^2/(^2−^2)$"? Alternatively, "\$2\alpha^2/(\alpha^2−\omega^2)\$", which should render similarilly/identically as $2\alpha^2/(\alpha^2−\omega^2)$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\eqa}{\approx}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\brlr}[1]{\left.#1\right|}$
$\newcommand{\deriv} [2]   {{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2} }}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\intcc} [2]  {{\left[#1:#2\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\intoo} [2]  {{\left(#1:#2\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\intoc} [2]  {{\left(#1:#2\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\intco} [2]  {{\left[#1:#2\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\ff}{\mathrm{f}}$
$\newcommand{\fF}{\mathrm{F}}$
$\newcommand{\fG}{\mathrm{G}}$
$\newcommand{\fg}{\mathrm{g}}$
$\newcommand{\fphi}{\mathrm{\phi}}$
$\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{dx}}$
$\newcommand{\dS}{\mathrm{ds}}$
$\newcommand{\dtau}{\mathrm{d\tau}}$
$\newcommand{\du}{\mathrm{du}}$
$\newcommand{\dv}{\mathrm{dv}}$
$\newcommand{\step}{\mu}$
$\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}$
$\newcommand{\thme}[1]{#1}$
$\newcommand{\opFT}{\mathrm{F}}$
$\newcommand{\opFT}{\mathrm{L}}$
$\newcommand{\opIFT}{\mathrm{IFT}}$
$\newcommand{\thme}[1]{#1}$
$\newcommand{\Real}{\mathrm{Re}}$

I'll be honest with you---it looks like there is no Inverse Fourier Transform for $2\alpha^2/(\alpha^2-\omega^2)$.
I'd be happy to be proven wrong...but at least consider the following...

(1) Let $s\eqd j\omega$. Then the Fourier Transform $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \fg(\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}\dtau$ of $\fg(\tau)$
becomes the (Two-Sided) Laplace Transform $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \fg(\tau)e^{-s\tau}\dS$ of $\fg(\tau)$.

(2) Note that what we want is a function $\fg(\tau)$ with Laplace Transform $\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+s^2}$. Why?
Because then when we substitute back in $s=j\omega$ we would get
$$\brlr{\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+s^2}}_{s=j\omega} = \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}$$
and the world would be a happier place.

(3) If only there was such a function $\fg(\tau)$ ... hmmmmm ... But wait! There *is* a function like that! In fact, if you happened to guess that the function $\fg(\tau)$ is
$$\fg(\tau)\eqd 2\sin(\omega\tau)\step(\tau)$$
where $\step(\tau)=1$ for $\tau\geq1$ and $0$ otherwise (the step function), then you would be right! And you can check that [here](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN9780738672458&pg=PA3) (where the One-Sided Laplace is used and so $\step(\tau)$ is implied).

(4) So the Inverse Laplace Transform of $\fG(s)\eqd\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+s^2}$ is $\fg(\tau)\eqd 2\sin(\omega\tau)\step(\tau)$. So we just set $s=j\omega$ and we're all done here, right? Well not quite. That Laplace Transform $\fG(s)$ has a Region of Convergence of $\Re(s)>0$, where $\Re(s)$ is the real component of the complex $s$. The problem here is that the Fourier Transform exists along the imaginary axis of $s$---that is, at $s=j\omega$, which means $\Re(s)=0$ ... which is *not* in the Region of Convergence of $\fG(s)$ ... and so rather, it **diverges** or "goes to infinity" or "blows up" at $s=j\omega$.

And so, while the Laplace Transform of $\fg(\tau)$ *does* exist (for $\Re(s)>0$), it does *not* exist (it diverges) for $\Re(s)\leq0$. And so by extension, it looks like the Fourier Transform $\fG(\omega)=\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}$ does *not* exist (because it is *not* in the Region of Convergence of $\fG(s)$).